# Phoenix framework: Submission of custom information via JSON or hidden form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to submit some information that is to be automatically calculated via a Javascript function after some client actions are finished (e.g. think of a whack-a-mole game where the score needs to be transmitted and recorded when the time is up).

I have a proper model for the information to be recorded. If I try to send the information as JSON, the `create` action from the controller runs fine. However, I don't seem to be able to easily redirect the user and show custom flash messages afterwards. (I'm used to the `put_flash` method which doesn't seem to work in this case).

Should I try to construct a hidden form on the page instead and try to fill the hidden input fields + trigger the "Submit" button via JS after the actions are finished? If not, what is the proper way to perform redirection + show flash messages if I interact with the controller via JSON POST requests? I think I didn't fully understand the mechanism of the flash messages.

---

EDIT: By default the controller code is just like:

```
case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, record} ->
    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "Record saved successfully.")
    |> redirect(to: record_path(conn, :index))
    ...

end
```

which apparently doesn't work on JSON requests.

Now I'm just doing:

```
   {:ok, lesson_record} ->
    conn
    |> send_resp(200, "success")
    ...
```

and letting the Javascript parse the response code and do the redirection. However I don't know how to display flash messages in this case.

Comment: Any chance you can show the controller code and any other applicable code?

Comment: @Bitwise I think the problem is that I'm not sure how to write the proper controller response. If I write `put_flash` then followed by `redirect`, just like on normal form submission, text content containing the new page is returned to the POST request, which apparently doesn't work. Should I use `put_resp_content_type("application/json")`, return a JSON with `redirect` field, and then manually run `window.location.replace(data.redirect)` in the Javascript? In that case I'm still not sure how to display the flash though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show flash message and redirect the user to *http* no matter what, why would you start with JSON POST in the first place? This looks like a normal HTTP POST.

One does not need to construct a hidden form though, just set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and construct the request like:

```
  const data = [
    encodeURIComponent(key1) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value1),
    encodeURIComponent(key2) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value2)
  ].join("&");
  const request = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: data
  };
  post_it(request);
```

With this type of request all your redirections, flash messages etc will perfectly work, since it’s a normal HTTP POST, that goes through the respective *default pipeline*.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually decided to go with a modal popup with using JSON, but if I want to stick with redirect + flash this should be exactly what's needed.